# Calc() in css3 using less is giving a wrong output

Tags: css, less

I have the following line of css code in my less file

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
    select#pseudoId {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 700;
        width: -moz-calc(100% + 10px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% + 10px);
        width: calc(100% + 10px);
    }
}
```

The issue is when it is rendered on browser and I check the developer tool is shows me width as **calc(110%)** which is not correct.

can someone help me with this, what needs to be done for it to render like **(500px + 10px)**

**(if 100% is 500px)

Comment: This happens in any particular browser or at all?

Comment: all the browser, initially i thought its just chrome behaving weird, but it shows the same in all the browsers